# Error: Could not connect to a host in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to import a CSV data file in my MongoDB collection transaction which I created in the Mongo Db Atlas.

I used the following connection string:
'''
'mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@reportingdata-n8b3j.mongodb.net/ecommerce?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --collection transactions --drop --type csv --headerline --file data.csv''
'''
It shows the following error : 
'''

2020-06-11T19:28:03.513+0545    WARNING: ignoring unsupported URI parameter 'retrywrites'
2020-06-11T19:28:05.849+0545    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AtlasError) Authentication failed.
'''

I am currently using mongo db 4.2

Comment: I had the `unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1"` message. I'm not sure what exactly fixed it, but after changing my password on Atlas everything seemed to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command, worked for me (you can find the command in the command line tools) also check if your IP is whitelisted, add your current IP.

```
mongoimport --host atlas-1jjmob-shard-0/reportingdata-shard-00-00.66vlq.mongodb.net:27017,reportingdata-shard-00-01.66vlq.mongodb.net:27017,reportingdata-shard-00-02.66vlq.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username admin --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db ecommerce --collection transactions --drop --type csv --headerline --file data.csv
```